# Sortable Handle, drag animation always left

Tags: html, list, jquery-ui-sortable, drag

im trying to flip the offset of the drag animation from the handle to the right, instead of the left. Whenever I want to drag it , the animation starts automatically from the leftside, when the handle is on the right. I want it to start from the right.

```
    <ol class='leerrails_list'>
    
       
       <li>
         <a href="leertraject.asp?dlt_id=<%=lt3_id%>"> 
        <div class = "leerrails_list_img" 
             style="background-image:url('/_domains/bz_bluelearning_nl/images/aanbod/feedback en Fu_up@2x.png');" ></div>
              <p>Feedback</p>
          <span class = "label2" >Managementrol</span>
          <div class = "leerrails_list_voortgang_blok">
               <div class = "leerrails_list_voortgang" style = "width:64px;"></div>
          </div>
          </a>
          <i class="fas fa-sort"></i>  
           </li>
          
    
          
            <li>
              <a href="https://bz.bluelearning.nl/leerplein/olo_inschrijven_bz.asp?lt_id=31">  
        <div class = "leerrails_list_img" 
            style="background-image:url('/_domains/bz_bluelearning_nl/images/aanbod/Beinvloeden van systemen@2x.png');"></div>
              <p>Beïnvloeden in het systeem</p>
          <span class = "label2" >Managementrol</span>
          <div class = "leerrails_list_voortgang_blok">
               <div class = "leerrails_list_voortgang" style = "width:64px;"></div>
          </div>
          </a>
          <i class="fas fa-sort"></i>  
           </li>
    
           
            <li>
              <a href="https://bz.bluelearning.nl/leerplein/olo_inschrijven_bz.asp?lt_id=38">  
        <div class = "leerrails_list_img" 
            style="background-image:url('/_domains/bz_bluelearning_nl/images/aanbod/Sturen_adviseren in een politiek bestuurlijke omgeving@2x.png');"></div>
              <p>Adviseren in een politiek-bestuurlijke omgeving</p>
          <span class = "label2" >Managementrol</span>
          <div class = "leerrails_list_voortgang_blok">
               <div class = "leerrails_list_voortgang" style = "width:64px;"></div>
          </div>
          </a>
          <i class="fas fa-sort"></i>  
           </li>
    
            <li>
              <a href="https://bz.bluelearning.nl/leerplein/olo_inschrijven_bz.asp?lt_id=21">  
        <div class = "leerrails_list_img" 
            style="background-image:url('/_domains/bz_bluelearning_nl/images/aanbod/love module@2x.png');"></div>
              <p>LOVE Module</p>
          <span class = "label1" >Persoonlijk leiderschap</span>
          <div class = "leerrails_list_voortgang_blok">
               <div class = "leerrails_list_voortgang" style = "width:64px;"></div>
          </div>
          </a>
          <i class="fas fa-sort"></i>  
           </li>
          
    
          <!--inactieve li -->
    
          
          <li class = "leerroute_item_inactief">
            <i class="fas fa-sort" style= "display:none;"></i>
            <div class = "leerrails_list_img"></div>
            <div class = "leerrails_list_inactief"></div>
              <p>Hier komt uw e-module</p>
            </li>
           
    
        
    </ol>
    
    <script>
      $(function  () {
      $("ol.leerrails_list").sortable();
      
    });
    
    
    $("ol.leerrails_list").sortable({
      group: 'no-drop',
      handle: 'i.fa-sort',
      onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
        // Duplicate items of the no drop area
        if(!container.options.drop)
          $item.clone().insertAfter($item);
        _super($item, container);
      }
    });
    
    
    </script>

<style>
 .leerroute_overige {
    position: relative;

   }

   @media (max-width:1060px){

      .leerroute_overige {
         position: relative;
         -webkit-margin-before: 10px;
         -webkit-margin-after: 40px;
         margin-bottom: 20px;
         width: 100%;
         left: 30px;
         margin-top: 0px;
     }
 }
      

   
 

 ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_img::before{
   content: '';
position: relative;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-flex;
left: -38px;
margin-right: -15px;
top: 30%;
 }

 ol.leerrails_list li.leerroute_item_inactief .leerrails_list_img::before{
   content: '';
position: relative;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-flex;
left: -38px;
margin-right: -15px;
top: 30%;
 }

 ol.leerrails_list .leerroute_actief {
   content: '';
   position: relative;
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-flex;
   left: -46px;
   margin-right: -15px;
   top: 30%;
   
 }

 ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_img::before:hover {
   content: '';
   position: relative;
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-flex;
   left: -46px;
   margin-right: -15px;
   top: 30%;
   
 }

 ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_img::before:first-of-type {
   content: '';
   position: relative;
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-flex;
   left: -46px;
   margin-right: -15px;
   top: 30%;
   
   
}

ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_img::before:visited {
   content: '';
   position: relative;
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-flex;
   left: -46px;
   margin-right: -15px;
   top: 30%;
   
   
}

ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_img::before:active {
   content: '';
   position: relative;
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-flex;
   left: -46px;
   margin-right: -15px;
   top: 30%;

}

ol.leerrails_list {

   list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: my-counter;
 }

 ol.leerrails_list a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    
 }


 ol.leerrails_list::before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   border-left: 4px dotted #8f8f8f;
   left: -24px;
   bottom: 0;
   top: 0;
   transform: translate3d(31px, 0, 0);
 }
 

 ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_img{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
   height:88px;
   width: 100px;
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position-x: center;   
   opacity: 1;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;

   
}

 ol.leerrails_list li p {
   position: relative;
top: 10px;
left: 20px;
text-align: left;
}

ol.leerrails_list span.label1 {
   position: relative;
   top: 0px;
   left: 20px;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 11px;
   background: #037912;
   color: white;
   padding: 5px;
   border-radius: 3px;
}

ol.leerrails_list span.label2 {
   position: relative;
   top: 0px;
   left: 20px;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 11px;
   background: #008DC2;
   color: white;
   padding: 5px;
   border-radius: 3px;
}



/*
ol.leerrails_list a {
   position: relative;
   margin: 20px 30px;
   color: white;
   top: 30%;
}
*/

ol.leerrails_list a:hover{
   background-size: 100px 100px;
   transition: .1s ease-in-out;
   position: relative;
   margin: 20px 0px;
   color: black;  
}



 
 
 ol.leerrails_list li.placeholder {
   position: relative;
   /** More li styles **/
 }
 ol.leerrails_list li.placeholder:before {
   position: absolute;
   /** Define arrowhead **/
 }

 ol.leerrails_list li::before{
   content: counter(my-counter);
   background: transparent;
   font-size: 25px;
   width: 2rem;
   height: 2rem;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display:block;
   line-height: 5.8rem;
   color: #7e7e7e;
   text-align: left;
   margin-right: 20rem;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
   margin-left: -60px;
    
 }
 
 /*

 ol.leerrails_list li.leerroute_item_inactief::before{
   content: counter(my-counter);
   background: transparent;
   width: 2rem;
   height: 2rem;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display:block;
   line-height: 5.8rem;
   color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
   text-align: left;
   margin-right: 20rem;
   position: absolute;
   left: -60px;
   
  
    
 }
 */
 

 ol.leerrails_list li {
   counter-increment: my-counter;
   font-family: 'Lato';
   height: 88px;
   width: 470px;
   background: white;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 2px #00000040;
   cursor: pointer;
}



ol.leerrails_list li.leerroute_item_inactief {
   counter-increment: my-counter;
   font-family: 'Lato';
   height: 88px;
   width: 470px;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
   border: 1px solid grey;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
   box-shadow: none;
}

ol.leerrails_list li.leerroute_item_inactief:hover{
   box-shadow: none;
}

@media (max-width:1060px){
   ol.leerrails_list li.leerroute_item_inactief {
      width: 90%;

   }

}

ol.leerrails_list li.leerroute_item_inactief p{
   margin: 17px 60px;
   /* text-align: center; */
   padding: 5px;
   color: grey;
   font-weight: 300;
}

/*
ol.leerrails_list li i.fas {
   position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
}
*/




ol.leerrails_list li i.fa-sort {
   font-size: 19px;
   position: relative;
   color: gray;
   border: none;
   padding: 8px;
   z-index: 100;
   float: right;
   top: -64px;
   
}



ol.leerrails_list li.leerroute_item_inactief i.fa-sort {
   font-size: 19px;
   position: absolute;
   
   margin-left: 85%;
   color: gray;
   border: none;
   padding: 6px;
   z-index: 100;
   
}
   
   


@media (max-width:1060px){

   ol.leerrails_list li {
      width: 90%;

   }


}



 ol.leerrails_list li:hover {
    z-index: 100;
   background: #f8f8f8;
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 3px #0000006b;
   transition: .1s ease-in-out;

 }


 ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_voortgang{
   height: 6px;
   background: rgba(0,200,83,1);
   top: 0px;
   position: relative;
   left: 0px;
   z-index: 0;
 }

 @media (max-width:1060px){
   ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_voortgang {
      width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
    

   }

 }

 ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_voortgang_blok {
   width: 370px;
   height: 6px;
   background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
   top: 23px;
   position: relative;
   left: 0px;
   z-index: 0;
   margin-left: 100px;
    
 }

 @media (max-width:1060px){
   ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_voortgang_blok {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
      max-width: -moz-available;

      }

 }

 ol.leerrails_list .leerrails_list_img .img_1 {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url("../images/aanbod/Diversiteit en inclusie.png");
 }
</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT5xe.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujegf.png)

Comment: This is probably being caused by your CSS, without seeing it there's no way to duplicate your issue.

Comment: i updated the part with the css
the api im using is https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Answer (score 0):

I [tested your setup](https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/muh0zk6p/24/) and it works well enough, the issue you showed doesn't occur. Make sure you have all the dependencies needed to run JQuery Sortable.

- jquery.js
- jquery-ui.js
- [jquery-ui.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css) (this is my guess on what you're missing)

Aside from the possible missing dependencies you have some strange things going on with your CSS setup. You should consider switching your layout for the draggable li's over to using Flex or Grid as opposed to a bunch of nested relative and absolute positioned containers especially because JQuery UI Sortable will add absolute positioning to the item being dragged which will cause some layout jump for nested relatively positioned items.

```
some code to keep Stack Overflow off my back for sharing a Fiddle, the code in the Fiddle is the original code shared.
```